# iPhone Camera app doesn't work but some other apps can still use it

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I have the iPhone X with latest iOS installed.

**Original Camera App:** Front Camera and Back Camera: Non of them work. Black screen.

**Third Party Camera Apps**: Same issue.

**SnapChat and Instagram:** Front Facing camera **works**!! but not back camera.

I check the "Voice Over" feature some websites were suggesting but I don't have it enabled anyways.
I have also done a “full restore factory settings” and backup/restore too.

So is it still a software issue or is it time to give up on this iPhone's camera?

Comment: Have you force restarted it? See: https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios

Comment: Force restart never resolved this for me and damages other apps since they can’t save their work @DavidSupportsMonica but it’s a valid thing to try if you have exhausted all the other steps first. I have seen this from time to time so it’s a real thing and not always hardware.

Comment: After the “full restore of factory settings” but  before restoring your apps and settings, did you test out the camera?  That’s the best time to test it out - in a “factory fresh” state.  If it doesn’t work there, you’ve narrowed down the potential suspects.

Comment: @Allan : Yes first I did a factory fresh meaning non of my own "restore" in it. Still didn't work.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica : OK tried that one too.  No luck.

Comment: Is your iPhone running low on storage space? I have experienced that running out of space causing iPhone camera to show a black screen.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that.  In that reset, there’s nothing to conflict with the Apple native apps and the camera other than iOS itself, so the last option is an update.  It may be fixed with the next release, but from this point, nothing you “restore” is going to fix it.  It might be time to replace it.

Comment: Just to make it relateable...I have an iPhone 7 Plus that’s slowly dying.  NFC (thus ApplePay) stopped working.  Display rotation just started failing and it will not turn on (reboot) without a hard reset.  I’ve done these same steps you did and came to the conclusion that it’s time to retire it but the only reason I haven’t done so already is that I’m hoping it will take me to the release of the iPhone 12 Pro.  But no matter how you slice it...it’s done and it’s time for a new model.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen this be a temporary situation.

1. Power off your phone - normal controlled shut down
2. Power it on - test camera app before you run any other app

If that fails, back up and restore the phone. I’ve not seen erase all content and settings fix this, but I always try that before I restore since it’s a lot faster and I’m about to reload a backup either way at that point.

Once you’re sure it’s not a software issue, then it’s time for a hardware repair or swap. Apple has replaced my camera module on that model phone and I was extremely satisfied with the results. Much cheaper than a new phone as well even if you pay for the repair instead of AppleCare or warranty.

Comment: done all these. Still No luck.

Comment: Well, there’s always your hardware has failed as a solution : - (